# How are Bootstrap styles generated using Sass

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass

I downloaded the npm bootstrap package, went into `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`, and looked at `.alert-danger` styles:

```
.alert-danger {
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
}
```

When I search those color codes, they do not appear in any other files.  Where are these codes being defined/calculated?
I’m interested in customizing those values using Sass, I’m trying to keep specificity overrides as my last resort.

Comment: the .alert-danger is defined in the scss/_alert.scss in line 47, bootstrap is using a loop to generate all the color type 'danger, warning, primary ...' in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the main colors in `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss` file, but the colors in the dist bootstrap.css file are not the same as the colors in _variables.scss,

bootstrap generates the dist colors from the main colors in _variables.scss:

```
lighten($table-dark-bg, 7.5%)

darken($link-color, 15%)

rgba($red, .1)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I got it almost figured out, I just need to know where color for `.alert-link` is at.  Would you happen to know?

Comment: its in scss/mixin/alert.scss

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  It's like a treasure hunt, lol.  Thanks!!

Comment: you can use the ack tool to make it easy to search a code. https://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: Yeah, I'll look more into grep search in visual studio code, maybe I was looking for wrong search terms, not sure.  Definitely needed some guidance at the time. :)